# Массив целых чисел в строку

Tags: c

Хочу перевести элементы целочисленного массива в строку.Думаю надо использовать itoa , но не могу понять, как записать.
Вот обычный массив int A1[50]; в его ячейках  уже есть нужные числа(переведенные десятичные числа в  двоичные типа такого 100101 ).Хочу записать его элементы в строку  char num2[100];

```
for(j=0;j<50;j++)
itoa(A1[j],num2,100);
```

Как использовать itoa и за что отвечает каждая подобная запись: вот второе - это указатель на строку , 100 - это буффер(кстати , каким должно быть его значение), а чем тогда должно быть первое ?
UPD Это не буффер, а еще я тут попытался сделать что-то

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
char p[17];
int i=0;
int A[5]={10,40,55,34,567};
while(i<5){
itoa (A[i], (p+i), 10);
i++;
}
i=0;
while(i<5)
printf("%4c",p[i++]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Прямо подряд или какие-то разделители между числами в строке хотите вставить? Впрочем, в любом случае можно воспользоваться [sprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) в цикле по элементам массива. Обратите внимание, эта функция возвращает количество выведенных символов, что позволяет легко правильно модифицировать ее первый аргумент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите все числа в одну строку записать, то можно так:

```
char p[...] = "";   // Тут надо побольше и обнулить первый сиимвол
int i=0;
int A[5]={10,40,55,34,567};
while(i<5)
{
    sprintf(p+strlen(p), "%d ",A[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Правельнее будет, конечно, использовать `snprintf` и следить за оставшимся местом в строке `p`.

Comment: Зачем же на каждом шаге вызывать strlen? Прочтите все же [man sprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf). Достаточно одной операции сложения для вычисления, куда писать.

Comment: @avp,а как вставить с помощью sprintf в самое начало строки открывающуюся скобку ?

Comment: @Elvin,   если считать, что   речь  идет о коде в ответе и `i  == 0` это начало, то как-то так -- `sprintf(p + strlen(p), "%s%d ", i ? "" : "(",  A[i]);`

Comment: @avp,я имею в виду, что имеется просто строчка stringin, куда записано a+b , и нужно поставить скобки с двух сторон

Comment: @Elvin, если уже записано и места достаточно, то проще сдвинуть (см. [memmove](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove)) и простыми присваиваниями разместить скобочки по краям

Comment: @avp,то есть memmove(stringin2,stringin2,1) сработает ? То есть я хочу сдвинуть массив на одну позицию вправо и присвоить уже нулевому '(' . И чтобы это осталось в том же самом массиве

Comment: @Elvin, наверное у вас какие-то проблемы с форматированием -) imho `memmove(stringin2 + 1, stringin2, l = strlen(stringin2)); stringin2[0] = '('; stringin2[l + 1] = ')'; stringin2[l + 2] = 0;` Т.е. не забывайте о затертом терминирующем строку нуле